# How does maven resolve the dependencies of the main dependencies on which our application is build?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-2, maven-3

I am trying to understand maven a little more. How is maven able to download the dependencies of the main dependency of the application? For example assuming my application has main dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now, when maven downloads this jar , it downloads the dependencies for this jar as well. For example, see the screen shot below:

[image]

As can be seen, maven has not only downloaded the hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.jar but also all it dependencies.

Now, my questions is how maven knows what are the dependencies for the "top-level" dependency, that is in this case the "top-level" dependency is hadoop-hdfs, so what all jars it has to download for this?

I see this as well in the .m2/respository for **hadoop-hdfs**:

[image]

## I opened the .pom file, the contents are (partly):

```
<project>
    ....

    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <description>Apache Hadoop HDFS</description>
    <name>Apache Hadoop HDFS</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
             <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
             <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>

    ...
</project>
```

What is this **hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.pom** ? Does this file give information to maven what are the dependencies to be downloaded for **hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.jar**?

Can anyone help me clear these things?

Answer (score 2):

> First of all you are right, the hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.pom tells Maven
>   about the libraries that hadoop depends upon. But, when using hadoop
>   as a dependency in your project, maven uses the below strategies to
>   finalize the list of dependencies in addition to using the
>   hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.pom.
>
> 1. If a dependency is specified with groupid, artifactid and version in the current project under the dependencies tag, it takes the first
>      precedence. This is how hadoop-hdfs got added in your project.
> 2. Dependency Management takes the next precedence. When a dependency is specified only with group and artifact id's under dependencies tag
>      but at the same time, the dependency is defined under
>      dependencyManagement tag with version and transitively inside hadoops pom.xml also,
>      the one under the dependencyManagement tag will be given preference.
> 3. Dependency Mediation takes the last precedence. Dependencies are resolved using dependency mediation. Meaning, in your case the 
>      dependencies mentioned inside hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.pom are the transitive
>      dependencies (indirectly depends on these dependencies since your
>      dependency "hadoop-hdfs" requires it) of your project and this process continues
>      recursively until all child dependencies are resolved.
>
> Note: There are other features such as excluding dependencies, marking
>   one optional and importing a list of dependencies. But they are used
>   sparsely. More information with examples can be found in the below URL
>
> [https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management][1]